# Ionic 4 Fab List opened by default

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on a new Ionic 4 project with a fab list. This list is working fine, but i would like to have it opened by default.

I've read some stuff here, but the code isn't working on Ionic 4.

Can somebody tell me a solution? Thanks!

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="start" slot="fixed" #fab >
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup-circle"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-list side="top">

        <ion-fab-button>
            <ion-icon name="navigate"  (click) ="this.startNavigation()" ></ion-icon>
          </ion-fab-button>

    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="thumbs-down" (click) ="this.doRating('-1')"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>

    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" (click) ="this.doRating('1')"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

And the page.ts file looks like:

```js
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonFabList } from '@ionic/angular'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('IonFabList',{static: false}) fab: IonFabList;

  constructor() {}

  ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    this.fab.toggleList();
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, stackbiltz tells me, that the fabs elements are "not a known elements"

Comment: You need to install the library

Comment: It's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `activated` property on the `ion-fab` elememnt.

```html
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="start" slot="fixed" activated="true" #fab >
</ion-fab>
```

Take a look at the [ion-fab docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab#properties)

Comment: Thanks if its correct could you accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers